# PDO cannot able to fetch image from database

Tags: php, database, image, pdo, blob

I've posted my code below. I can able to fetch the text values from database. But, i'm unable to fetch the image. i don't know where i made mistake?

```
      try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ebusers");
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->execute();
            while($userrow = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                echo "<table class=glowing width=800 border=0 align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td height=40 colspan=3 class=user_id >User ID : " . $userrow['UserID'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td bgcolor=wheat colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td width=334 rowspan=9 bgcolor=wheat align=center >';
                if( $userrow['UserProfilePicture'] >= '[BLOB - 0B]' )
                    {
                        echo '<img class=shadow_img width=160 height=180 src="data:image/png;base64,'  . base64_encode($userrow['UserProfilePicture']) . '"/>';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo '<img src=\'images/nophoto.gif\' class=shadow_img width=160 height=180 />';
                    }
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td bgcolor=wheat style=\"border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px;\" colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post an example value of `$userrow['UserProfilePicture']`

Comment: try changing `$userrow['UserProfilePicture'] >= '[BLOB - 0B]'` to `strlen($userrow['UserProfilePicture']) > 0` or `!empty($userrow['UserProfilePicture'])`

Comment: Which charset did you set the column in database to store the image?  If you had it set in `varchar` or such, then it'd not work.  It should be in charset in mime-type format if you wanted to retrieve an image out of a database.

Comment: @RickHoving : value of `$userrow['UserProfilePicture']` ? sorry, can't understand...

Comment: @Faron : img storage -> Type: LONGBLOB. but its worked when i use mysql query...

Comment: You are putting the `base64_encode` of `$userrow['UserProfilePicture']` as the image. If you can post an example value of what you are putting in the image I might be able to help you out further.

Comment: I mean what is the result of the following line of code: `echo '<img class=shadow_img width=160 height=180 src="data:image/png;base64,'  . base64_encode($userrow['UserProfilePicture']) . '"/>';`

Comment: @RickHoving : it simply shows the broken img symbol..

Comment: And what is the resulting html of the broken symbol? I'm looking for something like this `<img
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=
"/>`

Comment: @RickHoving : no i didn't get these kind of text. i'm getting simply this one http://postimg.org/image/6t242vw55/

Comment: @RickHoving : i tried separate coding. now i'm getting the text like what you posted above? `while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{echo base64_encode($row['UserProfilePicture']);   }`

Comment: Classic example of why not to store images in database

Comment: @davidstrachan : image are inserted into database correctly. i can see the value like this in db `[BLOB - 62.3  KiB]`

Comment: @user3181207 That not the point david was trying to make. You should upload files to the server and then insert the patches of uploaded files into a table.

Comment: @djay : okay. i will do it next time. now, i've storing few images only. So i have done it directly into db. could please tell me where is the error?

Comment: @user3181207  Instead of trying to fix this you should do as `djay` recommends. It will not only sort your problem but will improve the performance of your application.